# Is there an easy method to check is an NSRange passed to substringWithRange on NSString exists (so not to cause an error)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nested, nsrange

Say I pass the NSRange of (location: 5, length: 50) on the NSString "foo", that range obviously doesn't exist.

Is there a way to say `[string rangeExists:NSRange]` for instance, or do we have to manually validate the input?

Comment: I suspect the only thing you can do is check the length of the string first, then use that to ensure within range and avoid the exception.

Comment: There's two ways the range could be invalid: the `location` could be beyond the end by itself, or the `location` could be valid but the `length` too long. Does the distinction matter?

Answer (score 27):

You have to write your own check but it's simple enough:

```
NSString *str = ... // some string
NSRange range = ... // some range to be used on str

if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location + range.length <= str.length) {
    // It's safe to use range on str
}
```

You could create a category method on `NSString` that adds your proposed `rangeExists:` method. It would just be:

```
- (BOOL)rangeExists:(NSRange)range {
    return range.location != NSNotFound && range.location + range.length <= self.length;
}
```

Comment: `range.location + range.length` could overflow/wrap around  :)

Comment: @MartinR Yeah but only in very rare cases. I did update to check `location` for `NSNotFound`.

Comment: Yes, I did not mean that too seriously. But `range.location <= str.length && range.length <= str.length - range.location` might cover all situations.

Comment: @DougSmith Did this answer your question or are you looking for something different?

Answer (score 0):

If range A contains range B, the intersection of A & B should be B, the union of A & B should be A.
So in theory, both

```
NSEqualRanges(NSUnionRange(A, B), A)
```

and

```
NSIntersectionRange(A, B), B)
```

can be used to check if range A contains range B.

But if we pass a negative value to B.location, for the members of struct NSRange is NSUInteger, it will turn to a very large value. In this case,

```
NSUnionRange(A, B)
```

also returns A. It seems to be a bug. (Tested on macOS 10.14, Xcode 10.1)

so we choose NSIntersectionRange, like this:

```
NSString *str = @"foo";
NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, str.length);
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, 1);
if (NSEqualRanges(NSIntersectionRange(textRange, range), range)) {
    //safe
}
```

Comment: An answer consisting only on code is not consider a proper SO answer. Please explain also your reasoning along with the code (from review)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
if(selectedNSRange.location != NSNotFound && NSMaxRange(selectedNSRange) <= self.text.length)
```